# IP blocking with .htaccess in Apache 2.4 - Not Working

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, .htaccess, block

I want to block specific IP addresses but allow all others. I'm still struggling with this.

First I modified the `apache2.conf` file to look like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`AllowOverride` from `None` to `All`

Then added to `.htaccess` accordingly to the Apache2 documentation below:

> The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat,
>   are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid
>   using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

So, a more future-proof answer would be:

```
<RequireAll>
      Require all granted
      Require not ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    </RequireAll>
```

where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is my IP

In the `access.log` I see this:

> 10.10.10.5 (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) - - [27/Nov/2018:17:11:46 +0000]

Where  10.10.10.5 is the HA proxy.

It's still not working. Any ideas on what should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

> *”Where 10.10.10.5 is the HA proxy”*

Is your Apache behind a reverse proxy?

Because usually that will result in Apache seeing only the ip-address of the reverse proxy server as the client ip-address  (and not the actual ip-address of the client) which makes common ip-address restrictions impossible.

HAProxy can be configured to forward the actual client ip-address (see  https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy/proxy-protocol/) and Apache will need to be reconfigured to make use of that client ip address with https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html
and then you can expect to see client ip-address filtering work as expected in Apache httpd

Comment: HAProxy is already forwarding the client IP. I can see in the brackets my IP 10.10.10.5 (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX).  Apache must be configured somehow to use that IP.

Comment: That’s what mod-remoteip is for

Comment: I solved this by following this link: https://www.globo.tech/learning-center/x-forwarded-for-ip-apache-web-server/.